# Как правильно написать?

Tags: грамматика

Посоветуйте, как правильно написать предложение: "Он содержит общую и особенную части, состоящие из разделов, а те, в свою очередь, - из глав". Мне кажется, что оно составлено неправильно.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, нужно употребить не "он", а название книги, журнала, и т. п., то есть того, о чем идет речь. Во-вторых, "особенную" можно заменить на "дополнительную" или "специальную". В остальном, на мой взгляд, предложение составлено верно.

Answer (score 2):

Грамматически фраза правильна. Там, похоже, небольшая сложность с пунктуацией (запятые и  тире - что-то одно, похоже, лишнее), но я здесь её не комментирую.

А если вы о стилистике, то неблагодарное это дело к неспециалистам обращаться за стилистической правкой юридического текста. Тем более, что здесь, похоже, и нет особых стилистических некорректностей. Но коли уж такие сомнения, то единственный вопрос, это почему "он" (Кодекс, надо полагать?) **содержит** части, а они **состоят из**? Это все-таки разный смысл.

В меру своего непонимания сказал бы как-то так:

**"Кодекс состоит из общей и особенной частей, разбитых на разделы, в свою очередь делящихся на главы".**